# How to replace value in json file from another json file

Tags: java, python, json

I have a JSON file subDistricts.json.

```
{ 
    "subDistrictsStrs" : [
        { "addr_id":"001",
          "type":"sub_district",
          "name":"ตากแดด",
          "name_default":"ตากแดด",
          "child":"zip_codes",
          "child_id":"",
          "parent":"districts",
          "parent_id":"1234",
          "root_id":"1234",
          "is_active":true,
          "created_date":"2019-09-11 18:05:36",
          "updated_date":"2019-09-11 18:05:36"
        },
        { "addr_id":"002",
          "type":"sub_district",
          "name":"เกตรี",
          "name_default":"เกตรี",
          "child":"zip_codes",
          "child_id":"",
          "parent":"districts",
          "parent_id":"1234",
          "root_id":"1234",
          "is_active":true,"created_date":"2019-09-11 18:05:36",
          "updated_date":"2019-09-11 18:05:36"
        },
        { 
          //and more
        }
     ]
}
```

and I have another JSON file name.json.

```
[
  {
    "name": "กกกุง",
    "name_default": "Kok Kung"
  },
  {
    "name": "กกแก้วบูรพา",
    "name_default": "Kok Kaeo Burapha"
  },
  {
    "name": "กกโก",
    "name_default": "Kok Ko"
  },
  {
    "name": "กกดู่",
    "name_default": "Kok Du"
  },
  {
    /// and more
  }
]
```

How to change "name_default" in subDistricts.json based on "name" and "name_default" in name.json?

Suggest me python, java or other languages,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code:

```
import json

lst = [
  {
    "name": "กกกุง",
    "name_default": "Kok Kung"
  },
  {
    "name": "กกแก้วบูรพา",
    "name_default": "Kok Kaeo Burapha"
  },
  {
    "name": "กกโก",
    "name_default": "Kok Ko"
  },
  {
    "name": "กกดู่",
    "name_default": "Kok Du"
  }
]

with open("subDistricts.json", "rb") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for i in lst:
        for j in data.get("subDistrictsStrs"):
            if j.get("name") == i.get("name"):
                j.update(i)
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

python 3.7:

```
import json

with open("name.json", "r") as f:
    names = json.load(f)
    namesub = {x['name']: x['name_default'] for x in names }

print(json.dumps(namesub, indent=1, ensure_ascii=False))

with open("subDistricts.json", "r") as f:
    subds = json.load(f)

for d in subds['subDistrictsStrs']:
    d['name_default'] = namesub.get(d['name'], f"no mapping for {d['name']}")

with open("subDistrictsNew.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(subds, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: yeah! It works. But the results "name" it's not work. maybe it should set UTF8, how to set UTF8?  thank you.

Comment: @puthxii I updated the answer to deactivate the `ensure_ascii` flag.

Comment: Thank you. and thx for "no mapping for" It helps me to find errors very quickly.